# Audio conference using VoIP in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio-streaming, voip

My requirement is to make audio conference between iPhone and webpages, Is there possible to use VOIP to make the audio conference? can you please help is there any API is available for create audio conference using VOIP?

Regards
Sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look over - http://www.pjsip.org/

Answer (score 0):

mediastreamer2 (part of the linphone) I think they have audion conferencing module